# FP - abstract over flatMap

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

My FP skills are bit rusty. How would you call the following construction, and how can you make it so that `Seq[_]` is replaced by a generic `G[_]` (perhaps without assumption of `CanBuildFrom`):

```
trait Top {
  type F[A]

  def map    [A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => B     ): F  [B]
  def flatMap[A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => Seq[B]): Seq[B]
}

class ScalarExample extends Top {
  type F[A] = A
  def map    [A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => B     ): F  [B] = fun(xs)
  def flatMap[A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => Seq[B]): Seq[B] = fun(xs)
}

class SeqExample extends Top {
  type F[A] = Seq[A]
  def map    [A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => B     ): F  [B] = xs.map(fun)
  def flatMap[A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => Seq[B]): Seq[B] = xs.flatMap(fun)
}
```

So - I want to change in `Top` to

```
def flatMap[A, B, G[_]](xs: F[A])(fun: A => G[B]): G[B]
```

What is the best way to do that? Should I drop in an FP library -- can I do with minimal Cats or even smaller? What's the terminology for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take the definition:

```
trait Top {
  type F[A]

  def map    [A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => B     ): F  [B]
  def flatMap[A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => Seq[B]): Seq[B]
}
```

And lift `F` to be a higher kinded type defined on `Top`:

```
trait Top[F[_]]
```

And then re-write `flatMap` using `F`:

```
trait Top[F[_]] {
  def flatMap[A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => F[B]): F[B]
}
```

Then we basically get the first half of a Monad definition. All we need to do is add a way to lift any type `A` into an instance of `F[A]`:

```
trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]
  def flatMap[A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => F[B]): F[B]
}
```

With `pure` and `flatMap` (or `return` and `bind`, whichever you like) we get `map` for free. If you decide to use one of the functional libraries like Cats, you automatically get some monads for free, which extends Functor naturally and get a `map` for any monad instance.

---

If you want to go from `F` to `G`, we need a *natural transformation* for that. If we take Cats as an example, you can define one such for any `F` and `G`:

```
import cats.~>

val listToOptTransformer = new (List ~> Option) {
  override def apply[A](fa: List[A]) = fa.headOption
}
```

This makes sense, if you think about it. If you have an `F[A]`, the only way to get under the `F` to produce any kind of `B` is using `F.map`. But `F.map` can only yield `F[B]` by definition, not a `G[B]`. Thus, we can go:

```
  (flat)map  NT
F[A] -> F[B] ~> G[B]
```

i.e:

```
val listToOption: Option[String] = List(1,2,3).map(_.toString).headOption
```

We go:

```
   F[A]          F[B]             G[B]
List[Int] -> List[String] -> Option[String]
```

Comment: The problem I have is that there is no point at which I know both the concrete types of `F` and `G` statically, so I think I won't be able to derive a statically known natural transformation. So encapsulation wise, it would be much easier for me if I had an auxiliary method on `Top` that _takes_ like "half a transform", in the sense of `CanBuildFrom` (but perhaps simpler), if you understand what I mean. So that the caller doesn't need to know about `F`.

Comment: @0__ Can we require the method doing the transformation to take an implicit natural transformation from `F ~> G`? Meaning, any caller of this method must have such conversion in scope? Which sounds identical to `CanBuildFrom` to me. You can also equip them with the most useful transformations out of the box, like say `Seq ~> Option` and such.

Comment: @0__ For example: `def convert[F: Monad, G: Monad](implicit fToG: F ~> G)`

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think so :-( In other words, F and G are really patched together without knowing each other.

Comment: @0__ Can you give an example of such patching?

Comment: I accept the answer because it is correct with respect to the signature I posed; however, I figured the return type was different, so I posted the solution for that as separate answer; with that return type, the required operation is `traverse`.

Comment: @0__ Oh, you actually needed a `G[F[A]]`.. I see, then `traverse` makes perfect sense! Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, it turns out that the return type in my case must actually be slightly different. Instead of

```
trait Top {
  type F[_]
  def foo[G[_], A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => G[B]): G[B]
}
```

it has to be

```
trait Top {
  type F[_]
  def foo[G[_], A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => G[B]): G[F[B]]
}
```

after some feedback from Gitter's scala/scala, people pointed out to me that the abstraction needed is `Traverse`. It requires an `Applicative` type-class, then it works like this:

```
trait Top {
  type F[_]
  def traverse[G[_]: Applicative, A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => G[B]): G[F[B]]
}
```

With the `Id` and `List` monads:

```
class IdExample extends Top {
  type F[A] = A

  def traverse[G[_]: Applicative, A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => G[B]): G[F[B]] = f(fa)
}
```

and

```
class ListExample extends Top {
  type F[A] = List[A]

  def traverse[G[_], A, B](xs: F[A])(fun: A => G[B])
                          (implicit app: Applicative[G]): G[F[B]] =
    fa.foldRight(app.pure(List.empty)) { (a, lglb) =>
      app.map2(f(a), lglb)(_ :: _)
    }
```

(this uses the interfaces from Cats, but drops the `Eval` bloat from `foldRight`)